# NSDateFormatter not working when converting multiple formats

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdateformatter

I have a class which converts multiple date formats.

It works when I do this:

```
-(NSString*)getTimeStampWithFormat:(NSString*) formatStr{
    dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:formatStr];
    NSString *currentDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
    return currentDate;
}
```

it does not work when I do this

```
-(void) initDF{
    dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
}

-(NSString*)getTimeStampWithFormat:(NSString*) formatStr{
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:formatStr];
    NSString *date = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
        return currentDate;
}
```

I am calling the `getTimeStampWithFormat:` method multiple times to convert different formats. In the second approach, I am allocating memory only once and converting multiple times it gives nil.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Do you remember to call `initDF` first ?

Comment: Yes I check it and it is getting called. I actually tried converting in the initDF it was converting.

Comment: I assume you have return statements in that code?

Comment: how did you define dateFormatter? and where do you return the date in getTimeStampWithFormat ? Just one advice based on experience, I also have written myself a little method like this, there is really no need to save the dateFormatter - just allocate a new one every time - except if you run this thousand of times in a loop - otherwise it does not make any difference and just complicates your code...

Comment: Apple does recommend caching your date formatters because they are "expensive" to create...

Comment: Your second implementation does not return the dateFormatter value, so presumably its an instance field in the object.  But remember that that's an *instance* field, which means that if you set it in one object it's only set in *that* object, not in any others you may create.  NSLog the value of `dateFormatter` before you do `stringFromDate`.  I'll bet that it's nil.

Comment: (Yeah, date formatters aren't *that* expensive to create.  If you're using one in a loop, don't create it every time, and likewise try to move the set format stuff out of the loop.  But don't bust a gut minimizing the creations.)

Comment: I missed the last statement. I am returning currentDate. The class in which I am having this code is a singleton class so I am allocating it when the class is initialized Thats what I have done in second case where I allocate only once bu tit was not working. Do you think making it static helps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As apple said:

> Creating a date formatter is not a cheap operation. If you are likely to use a formatter frequently, it is typically more efficient to cache a single instance than to create and dispose of multiple instances. One approach is to use a static variable.

But I am wondering why it always return nil, could you please show us some of the format strings?

**Note: Any body know how to add comment to the question? I cannot find the 'comment' button.**

Comment: Commenting on other people's posts requires 50 reputation, that's why you can't see the Comment button just yet. [More info on privileges.](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges)

Comment: That's bad when I want to ask some details

Comment: True, but it's a necessary evil to combat spam-bots and excessive clutter. Don't fret though, you'll be at 50 Rep in no time! :)